# Default worksheet on workbook open

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried to macro my workbook select a specific worksheet but unsuccessfully. Please see picture attached for the code.

Any ideas how to fix it or what I have done wrong?
[image: vba]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your `workbook open` sub in **ThisWokrbook** rather than in the sheet.

Add this to **ThisWorkbook**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Run  "OpenSheet"

End Sub
```

and in a module add:

```
Sub OpenSheet()
'Activate Workbook
Workbooks("urworkbook.xls").Activate   
'Activate Worksheet
Workbooks("urworkbook.xls").Sheets("urSheet").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: are you saying that i should change the code to `Private Sub ThisWorkbook_Open()` or what, im not quiet sure what you mean.

Comment: you can call it private/public or just sub  if you like, but add that in the **ThisWoorkbook**. That will trigger the `Sub`from the module. Add module inside the VBA (top left corner droppdown)

Answer (score -2):

just some improvements to the Workbook_Open procedure : 
(It will display Full Screen, like a real application)

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
Run  "OpenSheet"
End Sub
```

Comment: If the OP had asked for it to display in full screen then this would be an improvement - but if a user isn't expecting full-screen in Excel, this can quickly cause confusion. Therefore this can't be referred to as an improvement based on the information we have. Users generally don't appreciate you messing with their UI without asking.

Comment: @MacroMan I understand your statement.